# "error": "415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: javascript, python, json, azure

I keep getting this error when making a POST request to my Flask API:

```json
{
    "error": "415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
}
```

This is my Flask API Python code that I want to call to fill details into an Azure SQL database:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pyodbc

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

# Database connection setup
SERVER = 'maidsqlppserver.database.windows.net'
DATABASE = 'miadsqlpp'
USERNAME = 'ysadmin'
PASSWORD = 'yellowsense@1234'
connectionString = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'

try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error connecting to the database:", e)

# Function to add custom headers to every response
@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://yellowsense.in'  # Replace with your frontend domain
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST'  # You can specify the allowed methods
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'  # You can specify the allowed headers
    return response

@app.route('/society_names', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def get_society_names():
    try:
        # Execute a SQL query to retrieve society names and IDs
        cursor.execute("SELECT society_id, society_name FROM Society")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Convert the result into an array of dictionaries with id and name
        society_data = [{"id": row.society_id, "name": row.society_name} for row in rows]

        return jsonify(society_data)  # Return JSON with id and name
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})

@app.route('/insert_maid', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def insert_maid():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        aadhar_number = data.get('aadhar_number')
        name = data.get('name')
        phone_number = data.get('phone_number')
        gender = data.get('gender')
        services = data.get('services')
        locations = data.get('locations')
        timings = data.get('timings')

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "EXEC InsertMaidRegistration ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?",
            (aadhar_number, name, phone_number, gender, services, locations, timings)
        )
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return jsonify({"message": "Maid entry added successfully"})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my frontend code in index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--   <h1>Time Slot Booking and Form</h1> -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="time-slots">
            <h2>Register a Worker</h2>
            <div class="slots" id="slots"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-container">
            <div class="search-tags">
                <!-- Tags selected by the user will be displayed here -->
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="tag-input" list="tags-list" placeholder="Search Apartment">
            <datalist id="tags-list"></datalist>
            <button id="add-tag">Add Apartment</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-container">
            <h2>Additional Information</h2>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            <br>
            <label for="aadhar">Aadhar Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="aadhar" name="aadhar" required>
            <br>
            <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" required>
            <br>
            <div class="gender-options">
                <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="MALE" required>
                <label for="male">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="FEMALE" required>
                <label for="female">Female</label>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="service-options">
                <label for="services">Services:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="maid" name="services" value="Maid">
                <label for="maid">Maid</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="nanny" name="services" value="Nanny">
                <label for="nanny">Nanny</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cook" name="services" value="Cook">
                <label for="cook">Cook</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="submit-button">Book Slots and Submit Form</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And for the frontend script.js (JavaScript):

```js
const slotsContainer = document.getElementById("slots");
const tagInput = document.getElementById("tag-input");
const addTagButton = document.getElementById("add-tag");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");

const startTime = 6; // Start time (6:00 AM)
const endTime = 30; // End time (6:00 AM of the next day)
const timeSlots = [];
const selectedTimeSlots = [];
const selectedTags = [];

// Generate time slots with 1-hour intervals
for (let i = startTime; i < endTime; i++) {
    const slotStartTime = i % 24;
    const slotEndTime = (i + 1) % 24;
    const slotLabel = `${slotStartTime.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00 - ${slotEndTime.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:00`;
    timeSlots.push(slotLabel);
}

timeSlots.forEach((slot) => {
    const slotElement = document.createElement("div");
    slotElement.classList.add("slot");
    slotElement.textContent = slot;

    slotElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
        slotElement.classList.toggle("selected");

        if (slotElement.classList.contains("selected")) {
            selectedTimeSlots.push(slot);
        } else {
            selectedTimeSlots = selectedTimeSlots.filter((time) => time !== slot);
        }
    });

    slotsContainer.appendChild(slotElement);
});

// Predefined tags
const predefinedTags = ["RPH", "SOMU SONNET", "PFR", "AS"];

function displayTags() {
    const searchTagsContainer = document.querySelector(".search-tags");
    searchTagsContainer.innerHTML = "";
    selectedTags.forEach((tag) => {
        const tagSpan = document.createElement("span");
        tagSpan.textContent = tag;
        tagSpan.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // Remove the tag when clicked
            selectedTags.splice(selectedTags.indexOf(tag), 1);
            displayTags();
        });
        searchTagsContainer.appendChild(tagSpan);
    });
}

// Function to populate the datalist with predefined tags
function populateDatalist() {
    const datalist = document.getElementById("tags-list");
    datalist.innerHTML = "";
    predefinedTags.forEach((tag) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = tag;
        datalist.appendChild(option);
    });
}

// Display predefined tags in the datalist
populateDatalist();

addTagButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const tag = tagInput.value.trim();
    if (tag !== "" && !selectedTags.includes(tag)) {
        selectedTags.push(tag);
        tagInput.value = "";
        displayTags();
    }
});

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Prepare the data to send
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const aadhar = document.getElementById("aadhar").value;
    const mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    const gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
    const services = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="services"]:checked')].map((checkbox) => checkbox.value);

    const data = {
        aadhar_number: aadhar,
        name: name,
        phone_number: mobile,
        gender: gender,
        services: services.join(', '),
        locations: selectedTags.join(', '),
        timings: selectedTimeSlots.join(', '),
    };

    // Send the data to the specified form URL
    sendDataToFormester(data);
});

function sendDataToFormester(data) {
    const formesterFormUrl = 'https://yellowsensebackendapi.azurewebsites.net/insert_maid';

    fetch(formesterFormUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', // Set the content type to JSON
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // Convert data to a JSON string
    })
        .then(() => {
            alert('Data submitted successfully to YellowSense.');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            alert('An error occurred while submitting data.');
        });
}
```

please let me know what the error is here and how to solve it. There are no CORS issues in the code as it returns the following successful output:

[image]

Comment: If you see your last screenshot, it says in Request Headers section: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", and your flask error says that it won't try to parse the received data as JSON because that header is not "application/json".